# Добавление значений в описание профиля пользователя AD с помощью PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

В профиле пользователя в AD, есть атрибут description.
С помощью PowerShell, добавляю пользователю в "Описание", какое-либо значение:

```
Set-QADuser i.ivanov -Description "Первое значение"
```

При повторном выполнении с другим значением, первое затирается.
Если я  правильно понял, то данный атрибут не имеет многозначных свойств.

Я сделал небольшой велосипед:

```
$var = Get-QADuser i.ivanov | Select Description
Set-QADuser i.ivanov -Description "$var ; Второе значение"
```

В итоге из-за того, что тип поля description не строка, 
значение $var - @{Description=Первое значение}

И я получаю в описании пользователя:

> @{Description=Первое значение} ; Второе значение

Можно ли в атрибут Description добавлять множественные значения?
Или как мне первое значение получить без @{Description=}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как мне первое значение получить без @{Description=}

Вас спасёт ExpandProperty:

`$var = Get-QADuser i.ivanov | Select -ExpandProperty Description`

Comment: Спасибо, спасло.